# Python curses string input while continuously updating a separate window?

Tags: python, select, command-line, curses

How can I simultaneously read a string as input in one window while updating another window? This is for using curses in Python.

This would be useful e.g. for having a program that displays some output which can happen at any time, even when the user is typing. The idea being that the user can continue to type without having the currently entered, semi-complete string get truncated or cut in the middle due to sudden output from the program.

I've tried to use and modify the code from this question: [Python/curses user input while updating screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152942/python-curses-user-input-while-updating-screen)

Since the code already exists in the other question I'm not posting it again here.

However, this code only reads a single character.

I can't just call getstr, as this will block and stop updating the other window until the user has entered a full string.

It might seem obvious how to solve it: Use threads. However, this is already warned against in the aforementioned question---curses doesn't play well with threads in Python, it seems.

Another "obvious" way to solve it would be to implement your own buffer, read one character at a time, implement basic editing, and keep using select to this in a non-blocking manner.

I am hoping that there is some way to read a string in a non-blocking manner while providing basic line editing (so I don't need to implement it myself!) using curses, as I can imagine this is a rather typical use case.

Here is an attempt using threading, modified from the aforementioned example code. The problem with this code is that it garbles the display. The display remains garbled until the window is resized, then it appears fine.

The code reads user input in one window (one thread), grabs a mutex, gives the string to some shared string, the other thread grabs the mutex, and displays it.

What is wrong with this code? What causes the garbled output? As soon as I remove the other thread manipulating curses (removing the getstr call), it stops being garbled.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import curses, curses.panel
import random
import time
import sys
import select
import threading

gui = None

class ui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.output_mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.output_str = ""

        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
#        curses.noecho()
        curses.echo()
        curses.cbreak()
        curses.curs_set(0)
        self.stdscr.keypad(1)

        self.win1 = curses.newwin(10, 50, 0, 0)    
        self.win1.border(0)
        self.pan1 = curses.panel.new_panel(self.win1)
        self.win2 = curses.newwin(10, 50, 0, 0)    
        self.win2.border(0)
        self.pan2 = curses.panel.new_panel(self.win2)
        self.win3 = curses.newwin(10, 50, 12, 0)
        self.win3.border(0)
        self.pan3 = curses.panel.new_panel(self.win3)

        self.win1.addstr(1, 1, "Window 1")
        self.win2.addstr(1, 1, "Window 2")

#        self.win3.addstr(1, 1, "Input: ")
#   user_input = self.win3.getstr(8, 1, 20)
#        self.win3.addstr(2, 1, "Output: %s" % user_input)

#        self.pan1.hide()

    def refresh(self):
        curses.panel.update_panels()
        self.win3.refresh()
        self.win2.refresh()
        self.win1.refresh()

    def quit_ui(self):
        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.curs_set(1)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()
        print "UI quitted"
        exit(0)


def worker_output(ui):
    count = 0
    running = 1

    while True:
        ui.win2.addstr(3, 1, str(count)+": "+str(int(round(random.random()*999))))
        ui.win2.addstr(4, 1, str(running))

        ui.output_mutex.acquire()

        ui.win2.addstr(5, 1, ui.output_str)

        ui.output_mutex.release()

        ui.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)


class feeder:
    # Fake U.I feeder
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
        self.ui = ui()
        self.count = 0

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        self.feed()

    def feed(self):
        threads = []
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker_output, args=(self.ui,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

        user_input = ""

        while True:
            self.ui.win3.addstr(1, 1, "Input: ")
            user_input = self.ui.win3.getstr(1, 8, 20)
            self.ui.win3.addstr(2, 1, "Output: %s" % user_input)
#            self.ui.refresh()
#            self.ui.win3.clear()

            self.ui.output_mutex.acquire()

            self.ui.output_str = user_input

            self.ui.output_mutex.release()

            time.sleep(.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = feeder()
    f.run()
```

Comment: If I were to do this, I might—for efficiency—split the problem into several threads: one that uses Python-curses *only* to update the screen, one that *only* reads from the terminal (directly from sys.stdin, probably, but coordinating with the screen-updater as needed), and some locks to coordinate everything. Your main thread can then deal with input when and as it appears by inspecting data structures, and doing a condition-variable wait when there's nothing else to do. (The idea here is to bypass curses-not-behaving-well-with-threads by having curses operated *only* from the one thread.)

Comment: @torek this would be the thread approach yes: However, from the other question it seems this is not a safe approach?

Comment: Unless there's something non-obvious, driving the curses code from a single thread *should* be safe. My impression from the comment there is that driving it from more than one thread is *not* safe (which would be unsurprising).

Comment: @torek I've added some code to my question that attempts to do this. It garbles the display.

Comment: The thread running `worker_output` calls curses functions (`ui.win2.addstr`), and the main thread running `feed` also calls curses functions (`ui.win3.addstr`). Don't do that! :-)

Comment: @torek Right, thanks, but even after commenting out the two addstr calls the display is still garbled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a somewhat different approach from what is in the comments: making a thread-based system that holds locks around various points.

This seems to work more or less minimally, though it exposes a lot of the annoyance of the curses library too, and is in general probably the wrong way to do things.  Still, I present it here as an example of one way to make this work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import collections
import curses, curses.ascii, curses.panel
import random
import time
import sys
import select
import threading

#gui = None

class LockedCurses(threading.Thread):
    """
    This class essentially wraps curses operations so that they
    can be used with threading.  Noecho and cbreak are always in
    force.

    Usage: call start() to start the thing running.  Then call
    newwin, new_panel, mvaddstr, and other standard curses functions
    as usual.

    Call teardown() to end.

    Note: it's very important that the user catch things like
    keyboard interrupts and redirect them to make us shut down
    cleanly.  (This could be improved...)
    """
    def __init__(self, debug=False):
        super(LockedCurses, self).__init__()
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

        # ick!
        self.panel = self

        # generic cond var
        self._cv = threading.Condition(self._lock)
        # results-updated cond var
        self._resultcv = threading.Condition(self._lock)

        self._workqueue = collections.deque()
        self._starting = False
        self._running = False
        self._do_quit = False
        self._screen = None
        self._ticket = 0
        self._served = -1
        self._result = {}
        self._debug = debug

    def start(self):
        assert(not self._running)
        assert(self._screen is None)
        self._screen = curses.initscr()
        with self._lock:
            self._starting = True
            super(LockedCurses, self).start()
            while self._starting:
                self._cv.wait()
        self.debug('started!')

    def run(self):
        # This happens automatically inside the new thread; do not
        # call it yourself!
        self.debug('run called!')
        assert(not self._running)
        assert(self._screen is not None)
        curses.savetty()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        self._running = True
        self._starting = False
        with self._lock:
            self._cv.notifyAll()
            while not self._do_quit:
                while len(self._workqueue) == 0 and not self._do_quit:
                    self.debug('run: waiting for work')
                    self._cv.wait()
                # we have work to do, or were asked to quit
                self.debug('run: len(workq)={}'.format(len(self._workqueue)))
                while len(self._workqueue):
                    ticket, func, args, kwargs = self._workqueue.popleft()
                    self.debug('run: call {}'.format(func))
                    self._result[ticket] = func(*args, **kwargs)
                    self._served = ticket
                    self.debug('run: served {}'.format(ticket))
                    self._resultcv.notifyAll()

            # Quitting!  NB: resettty should do all of this for us
            # curses.nocbreak()
            # curses.echo()
            curses.resetty()
            curses.endwin()
            self._running = False
            self._cv.notifyAll()

    def teardown(self):
        with self._lock:
            if not self._running:
                return
            self._do_quit = True
            while self._running:
                self._cv.notifyAll()
                self._cv.wait()

    def debug(self, string):
        if self._debug:
            sys.stdout.write(string + '\r\n')

    def _waitch(self):
        """
        Wait for a character to be readable from sys.stdin.
        Return True on success.

        Unix-specific (ugh)
        """
        while True:
            with self._lock:
                if not self._running:
                    return False
            # Wait about 0.1 second for a result.  Really, should spin
            # off a thread to do this instead.
            l = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.1)[0]
            if len(l) > 0:
                return True
            # No result: go around again to recheck self._running.

    def refresh(self):
        s = self._screen
        if s is not None:
            self._passthrough('refresh', s.refresh)

    def _passthrough(self, fname, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.debug('passthrough: fname={}'.format(fname))
        with self._lock:
            self.debug('got lock, fname={}'.format(fname))
            if not self._running:
                raise ValueError('called {}() while not running'.format(fname))
            # Should we check for self._do_quit here?  If so,
            # what should we return?
            ticket = self._ticket
            self._ticket += 1
            self._workqueue.append((ticket, func, args, kwargs))
            self.debug('waiting for ticket {}, fname={}'.format(ticket, fname))
            while self._served < ticket:
                self._cv.notifyAll()
                self._resultcv.wait()
            return self._result.pop(ticket)

    def newwin(self, *args, **kwargs):
        w = self._passthrough('newwin', curses.newwin, *args, **kwargs)
        return WinWrapper(self, w)

    def new_panel(self, win, *args, **kwargs):
        w = win._interior
        p = self._passthrough('new_panel', curses.panel.new_panel, w,
                              *args, **kwargs)
        return LockedWrapper(self, p)


class LockedWrapper(object):
    """
    Wraps windows and panels and such.  locker is the LockedCurses
    that we need to use to pass calls through.
    """
    def __init__(self, locker, interior_object):
        self._locker = locker
        self._interior = interior_object

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        i = self._interior
        l = self._locker
        a = getattr(i, name)
        if callable(a):
            l.debug('LockedWrapper: pass name={} as func={}'.format(name, a))
            # return a function that uses passthrough
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: l._passthrough(name, a,
                                                          *args, **kwargs)
        # not callable, just return the attribute directly
        return a


class WinWrapper(LockedWrapper):
    def getch(self):
        """
        Overrides basic getch() call so that it's specifically *not*
        locked.  This is a bit tricky.
        """
        # (This should really test for nodelay mode too though.)
        l = self._locker
        ok = l._waitch()
        if ok:
            return l._passthrough('getch', self._interior.getch)
        return curses.ERR

    def getstr(self, y, x, maxlen):
        self.move(y, x)
        l = 0
        s = ""
        while True:
            self.refresh()
            c = self.getch()
            if c in (curses.ERR, ord('\r'), ord('\n')):
                break
            if c == ord('\b'):
                if len(s) > 0:
                    s = s[:-1]
                    x -= 1
                    self.addch(y, x, ' ')
                    self.move(y, x)
            else:
                if curses.ascii.isprint(c) and len(s) < maxlen:
                    c = chr(c)
                    s += c
                    self.addch(c)
                    x += 1
        return s


class ui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.curses = LockedCurses()
        self.curses.start()
        #self.stdscr.keypad(1)

        self.win1 = self.curses.newwin(10, 50, 0, 0)
        self.win1.border(0)
        self.pan1 = self.curses.panel.new_panel(self.win1)
        self.win2 = self.curses.newwin(10, 50, 0, 0)
        self.win2.border(0)
        self.pan2 = self.curses.panel.new_panel(self.win2)
        self.win3 = self.curses.newwin(10, 50, 12, 0)
        self.win3.border(0)
        self.pan3 = self.curses.panel.new_panel(self.win3)

        self.win1.addstr(1, 1, "Window 1")
        self.win2.addstr(1, 1, "Window 2")
        self.win3.addstr(1, 1, "Input: ")

        self.output_str = ""
        self.stop_requested = False

    def refresh(self):
        #self.curses.panel.update_panels()
        self.win3.refresh()
        self.win2.refresh()
        self.win1.refresh()
        #self.curses.refresh()

    def quit_ui(self):
        self.curses.teardown()
        print "UI quitted"


def worker_output(ui):
    count = 0
    running = 1

    while not ui.stop_requested:
        ui.win2.addstr(3, 1, str(count)+": "+str(int(round(random.random()*999))))
        ui.win2.addstr(4, 1, str(running))

        ui.win2.addstr(5, 1, ui.output_str)

        ui.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        count += 1


class feeder:
    # Fake U.I feeder
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
        self.ui = ui()
        self.count = 0

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        try:
            self.feed()
        finally:
            self.ui.quit_ui()

    def feed(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker_output, args=(self.ui,))
        t.start()

        user_input = ""

        while not user_input.startswith("q"):
            self.ui.win3.addstr(1, 1, "Input: ")
            user_input = self.ui.win3.getstr(1, 8, 20)
            self.ui.win3.addstr(2, 1, "Output: %s" % user_input)
            self.ui.refresh()
            self.ui.win3.clear()

            time.sleep(.2)
        self.ui.stop_requested = True
        t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = feeder()
    f.run()
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the bottom window is only visible until the user has typed a string and hit enter -- when the next string is entered, the window is missing entirely, but user input is still functional. I'm surprised at how difficult this appears to be, I would think this is a pretty normal use case for curses and one of the good reasons to use curses over a pure terminal driven UI, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The disappearing window is due to the way curses works. It doesn't have a proper 2.5-dimensional data structuring system, so it's way too easy to have one window wreck another.

Comment: are you saying this is a limitation in your code example (which is fine!), or a limitation in curses? I can barely write code for curses at all, but surely it must be possible to have two windows like this and prevent one from disappearing?

Comment: It's a limitation in curses-in-general: you must make sure that windows never overlap, or if they do, carefully construct your updates so that the right one is on top. (Window borders are not permanent either!) You can sometimes use `subwin` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43381467/1256452) but beware, it too has horrible characteristics. While ncurses is better than the original 1980s curses, the 1980s one was so bad that I threw it all out when I wrote my original character-based windowing system. It's really just a terrible horrible no-good programming model; it's no wonder it never caught on.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. That's certainly disappointing. Are there any modern alternatives that you're aware of, which solve this basic problem, that support Python?

Comment: I don't know of any. People mostly seem to use [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) instead these days, which works fine within X and is more generally capable anyway.